# My Contact-us not working

Tags: laravel, contacts

I am doing it a contact-us page on Laravel 5.6 and I come across an error `'address' => $ recipient-> email,`
My contactController

```
  public function store(ContactFormRequest $request)
{
    $contact = [];
    $contact['name'] = $request->get('name');
    $contact['email'] = $request->get('email');
    $contact['msg'] = $request->get('msg');
    Mail::to(config('mail.support.address'))->send(new ContactEmail($contact));
    flash('Your message has been sent!')->success();
    return redirect()->route('contact.create');
}
```

My ContactEmail

```
 public function __construct($contact)
{
    $this->contact = $contact;
}


public function build()
{
    return $this
        ->to(config('mail.support.address'))
        ->subject('HackerPair Inquiry')
        ->view('emails.contact');
}
```

[image]

Comment: show us `mail.support.address` variable in your config file

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple things you need to fix. 
We'll start with the nature of your question. The mail facade expects an object you are passing an array to it.

Look at the registercontroller. Youll see how a user is made and can copy and change that to the desired object for your contact.